# Qcircuit: Different shapes or colors for multigate

Tags: diagrams

I have a noise term that I am implementing as a Multigate. Is there a way I can make this specific multigate stand out: such as different shapes or colors for this specific gate? Or even a dashed or dotted gate?

Comment: Perhaps you can show what you exactly do in form of a self-contained and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Voted unclear: no MWE after request.